# Get print from hp printer using iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, printing

I am trying to get a print of a pdf file from my iPad app but i am unable to find any thing around. I have check apple air printer sample code but it is not finding my HP printer 2100. my printer is in LAN. can anyone help me? I am stuck badly so please help me

Comment: can u find the printer and get a print with other apps such as safari?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution for printing in iOS is using the AirPrint API, and having a printer that supports it.

If this is for your own use, you can look at running a PC-based AirPrint server, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821703/how-to-use-linux-to-set-up-free-airprint-server-for-any-printer-from-ios-devices (closed question, but some info in there)

Comment: I've successfully printed on a receipt printer from an iPad using NSURLConnection/WLAN. The printer is attached to a unix desktop via serial line - so no AirPrint API.

Comment: Well yes, but that is a bit of a work-around. I mean that there is no way to print to a regular networked printer, or a Windows shared printer, the same way that you can from a desktop OS.